# How to make an Inputfield change its design when active?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, toggleclass

Let's say my background color is red.
I want the input textfield to appear red, but when you click inside the input field to type it becomes a regulad textfield. And ofcourse when you are not active in the input field it should be back to its original state (red).

Its actually something you see quite often. 
I thought of using toggleclass?

My input fields are all appended with jQuery

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the new pseudo classes in CSS3, the :focus selector here...

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act

CSS example:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus {  
    background:#f00;  
    border:3px solid #0f0;  
}
```

Hope that helps,
-fs

Comment: This doesn't work in IE7, and it doesn't work in IE8 with old doctypes.

Comment: thankyou! it works the other way around but it works! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: because of 'focus'?

Comment: :focus is a CSS 2 pseudo class selector. Other than that, this would be my preferred solution.

Comment: Yes mines too! Only one thing, it now is RED when its active, but i want it to be regular on active and red when its not active. How do you call that?

Comment: Define a css class for input, make this red, then make another with input:focus and set it up however you'd like. Sorry re: css3 vs 2, I have html5 on the brain.

Comment: @Francis Shanahan Thank you very much for your help! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You could do that either with a `css class` or style propertys.

css:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').bind('focusin', function() {
       $(this).removeClass('red');
    }).bind('focusout', function() {
       $(this).addClass('red');
    }).trigger('focusout');
});
```

example:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/NdyGJ/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input').bind('focusin focusout', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

I've created an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FBPaA/

It's working in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: my input fields are a class also can i use $('.input').bind ?

Comment: What do you mean by they are a class?